# Supabase realtime connection failing when custom JWT is used

Tags: supabase, supabase-database

I'm using supabase self-hosted and auth0 for my authentication instead of the default authentication provided by supabase. So I'm signing my auth0's payload with supabase secret and sending it in headers.

```
const payload = {
    userId: user.email,
    exp: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 60 * 60,
}
const accessToken = jwt.sign(payload, SUPABASE_SECRET_KEY)

const options = {}

if (accessToken) {
  options.global = {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
    },
  }
}
const supabase = createClient(supabaseUrl, supabaseAnonKey, options)
supabase.channel('custom-update-channel')
.on(
  'postgres_changes',
  { event: 'UPDATE', schema: 'public', table: 'user_notifications' },
  (payload) => { 
      console.log('Change received!', payload)
  }
)
.subscribe()
```

I also enabled the RLS policy on my table. Using the above headers I'm able to query my database. Now I wanted to enable real-time on my table. But when I try to create a subscription with my custom headers, the Realtime web socket connection throws an Authentication error. When I don't send the custom JWT in the header, it works fine but I need my custom JWT's payload to be stored in the subscription table. realtime so that I can use it on my RLS Policy. What should I do to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use self-hosted supabase, kong will allow only an anon key or service key to be passed as an API key. To set our custom token we can do something like this:

```
const supabase = createClient(supabaseUrl, supabaseAnonKey, options)
supabase.realtime.accessToken = 'custom jwt'
```

Directly setting access token in realtime client.

Answer (score 2):

Row Level Security (RLS) will fail if you are missing certain properties from your JWT. In your case you are probably using the `auth.uid()` function in your RLS which relies on a `sub` property for the user id. You need to add that to your JWT along with your existing `userId` property.

```
const payload = {
  userId: user.email,
  sub: user.id, // this must correspond with a user id in the table you are testing your RLS policy against
  exp: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 60 * 60,
}
const accessToken = jwt.sign(payload, SUPABASE_SECRET_KEY)
```